# How can I always move a text message to the position of a new message?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I hope I have selected the appropriate question here. I am currently in the process of coding some sort of "sticky" message.

Everything for it is already in place, but I am having a bit of trouble with the event.

What I tried is to check with an `on_message` event all messages and after each message this defined message is posted. But the old one is not deleted. *Is this possible with `discord.py` at all?*

I thought about a `fetch` of the message, but didn't find anywhere a method to delete this defined message and then post it again.

My code looks like this:

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content and message.channel.id == 777073533687300106:
            embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.gold())
            with open('sticky.json', 'r') as file:
                data = json.load(file)
            sorted_data = {id: text for id, text in sorted(data.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[1])}

            for pos, (id, text) in enumerate(sorted_data.items()):
                embed.description = f"{text}"
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            return
```

I hope I can find an answer here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `message` with `channel.fetch_message`.

```py
old = await message.channel.fetch_message(id) #not sure which id you want to use 
await old.delete() 
await message.channel.send(embed=old.content)
```

From what you are trying, I think you need to get the `created_at` attribute to sort messages by creation time. I don't understand why you are setting `embed.description = text` inside a for loop, it will simply overwrite all the other text values, and you will only have a single text.

References:

- [fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)
- [message.delete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20delete#discord.Message.delete)

Note: You might also want to check for permissions before deleting the message, could throw an error